# arcpy.Append_management ERROR 001156 - overshoot field length issue

Tags: arcpy, error-001156

I append features from one class to other (using arcpy.Append_management including FieldMappings). The issue is I overshoot the length of target field. I do wonder why Append_management does not deal with such issue, anyway...

For now I can increase the length of target field which fixed the issue. But I still need somehow check the length of input string. And do sub-string if needed so the tool won't crash whenever there too long string in input data. Any simple way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

I decided to not use **arcpy.Append_management** as it crashes on input longer than length of target field. As far as I know there is no way to check. For this reason I would suggest NOT to use **Append** together with **field_mapping** unless you are completely sure the inputs can't hit the length limitation of output.

Not sure if **Append** checks input/output field length when not using field mapping. If it checks only field names and types there is again space for crash.

At the end I decided to use combination of **arcpy.da.SearchCursor** and **arcpy.da.InsertCursor** and before Insert use slicing with the *target field length* to make sure there is no overshoot.